# Laravel 5.2 how do i render a variable like {{$post->reply->render}}

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
@foreach($post->reply as $replies)
   //code .....
@endforeach
```

how do I paginate the views for replies variable in this case

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: how do i get the paginated record of a variable object.. instead of {!! $post-> render()!!}  i want to paginate {$post->replies-> render()!!}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
@foreach($post->reply()->paginagte() as $replies)
    //code .....
@endforeach
```

Comment: Tanks but how do i use the render function for this page view

Comment: Assign the paginate to a variable so you can use it again instead of re-query it, @foreach(($paginate = $post->reply()->paginate()) as $reply), then after foreach you can use $paginate->render()